# redis-cli is not writing data when data is piped via kafka

Tags: redis, apache-kafka

Trying to push Kafka stream data into the Redis, command does not raise any error, and nothing gets to write into Redis.

Here is the command:

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning  | redis-cli -x rpush stepanova
```

It does not write anything to the "stepanova" key.

Is there something missing?

Comment: I have made it working by using following way:

./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning | while read data; do redis-cli rpush stepanova $data done

Feedback welcome if there is some better way to do this.

Comment: check redis db 0(default). It must be getting pushed into that as you have not selected an redis database.